# Webpack 4 and jQuery injection

Tags: javascript, jquery, webpack

I am trying to upgrade my (actually very simple) build process to Webpack 4 and I am encountering an issue, when jQuery seems to be injected incorrectly - mainly resulting in some third party plugins not being available in jQuery via $, even thought $() itself is available. It seems to me, like those plugins are getting different instance of jQuery or something.

Framework is `Yii2`, but it by itself is not providing any jQuery. Files are then provided in order (via `head/script` tag) `vendor`, `application`, `yii`, then some inline javascript as needed.

Everything worked fine with Webpack 1.15, but there were massive changes in between and I thought, that I have some free time, so let's upgrade.

Following is my webpack configuration (it is invoked from gulp via webpack-stream):

```
'use strict';

const path = require('path'),
    webpack = require('webpack');

module.exports = {
    mode: 'production',
    context: path.resolve(__dirname, 'main/assets/scripts'),
    entry: {
        // general
        'application': './application.js',
        'vendor': [
            'retinajs',
            'jquery',
            'bootstrap-sass',
            'peity',
            'metismenu',
            'pace',
            'toastr',
        ],

        // education/lecture
        'education/lecture/lecture-classes': './education/lecture/lecture-classes',

        // education/nomination
        'education/nomination/request-form': './education/nomination/request-form',

        // job-catalogue
        'job-catalogue/job-positions-listing': './job-catalogue/job-positions-listing',
    },
    output: {
        filename: '[name].js',
    },
    plugins: [
        new webpack.ProvidePlugin({
            $: 'jquery',
            jQuery: 'jquery',
            'window.jQuery': 'jquery',
            toastr: 'toastr',
        }),
    ],
    optimization: {
        minimize: false,
        runtimeChunk: {
            name: 'vendor'
        },
        splitChunks: {
            cacheGroups: {
                default: false,
                commons: {
                    test: /[\\/]node_modules[\\/]/,
                    name: 'vendor',
                    chunks: "initial",
                    minSize: 1
                }
            }
        }
    },
    module: {
        rules: [
            {
                test: /[\/\\]node_modules[\/\\]some-module[\/\\]index\.js$/,
                loader: 'imports?this=>window',
            },
            {
                test: /[\/\\]node_modules[\/\\]some-module[\/\\]index\.js$/,
                loader: 'imports?define=>false',
            },
            {
                include: require.resolve('jquery'),
                loader: 'exports-loader?window.jQuery'
            },
            {
                enforce: "pre",
                test: /\.js$/,
                exclude: /node_modules/,
                loader: "eslint-loader",
            },
            {
                test: /\.(js|jsx)$/,
                exclude: /(node_modules|bower_components)/,
                use: {
                    loader: 'babel-loader',
                    query: {
                        presets: ['es2015', 'react', 'stage-3'],
                        cacheDirectory: true,
                    },
                }

            },
        ],
    },
    resolve: {
        alias: {
            'jquery': 'jquery/src/jquery',
            'toastr': 'toastr/toastr',
            'pace': 'pace-progress/pace',
            'global': './global',
            'metismenu': 'metismenu/src/index',
            'bootstrap-sass': 'bootstrap-sass/assets/javascripts/bootstrap',
        }
    }
};
```

Is there something obviously wrong?
Btw, if I leave `window.jQuery` in ProvidePlugin, extra error `window.jQuery is not a function` pops up.
Also, if I just inject full vendor code to each of the JS chunks, it works fine, but I'd rather not do it.